# Unable to load provider

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I am trying to use an angular provider so I can dynamically load sub-modules within the $routeProvider of my angular application.  However, I am getting one of 2 errors:

`Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MainApp due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MyRouteProvider`

`Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MainApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Here's what I have:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : '',
    version : '1.0',
});

require([
    'app',
    'my-route-mod/my-route-mod.module',
    'my-route-mod/my-route-mod.provider',
    'main-app/main-app.config',
    'main-app/main-app.run',
    /* other initial modules */
],function(){
   angular.bootstrap(document,['MainApp']);
});
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    /* global angular, $ */

    angular.module('MainApp',[
        'MyRouteMod', /* This module does not want to load */
        'ngRoute',
        'ngCookies'
    ]);
})();
```

**my-route-mod/my-route-mod.module.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    /* global angular */

    angular.module('MyRouteMod',[]);
})();
```

**my-route-mod/my-route-mod.provider.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    /* global angular */

    angular.module('MyRouteMod')
    .provider('MyRouteModProvider',Provider);

    Provider.$inject = [];

    function Provider() {
        var provider = this;
        provider.$get = function () {
            return { route : someFunction };
        }

        function someFunction(){...}
    }
})();
```

**main-app/main-app.config.js**

```
(function(){
    /* global angular */
    'use strict';
    angular.module('MainApp').config(Config);

    Config.$inject = [
        'MyRouteModProvider',
        '$routeProvider',
        '$locationProvider',
        '$controllerProvider',
        '$compileProvider',
        '$filterProvider',
        '$provide'
    ];

    function Config(
        MyRouteModProvider,
        $routeProvider,
        $locationProvider,
        $controllerProvider,
        $compileProvider,
        $filterProvider,
        $provide
    ) {

        /* ... do some config stuff ... */
    }
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head><title>My App</title></head>
    <body>
        <!-- Some other stuff -->
        <div ng-view></div>
        <!-- Some other stuff -->

        <script src="vendor-stuff"></script>
        <script src="vendor/require.js" data-main="main">/script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I took requirejs out of the equation and was getting the same issue with the provider not loading.

I either get that MainApp is not available, or that MyRouteMod is not available, or that MyRouteModProvider is not available.

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular naming conventions.  For providers, the string 'Provider' gets added to your constructor name.  So, if you have:

```
angular.module('MyMod').provider('MickeyMouse',Provider);
```

Then angular will look for `'MickeyMouseProvider'`.  So, if you do

```
angular.module('MyMod').provider('MickeyMouseProvider',Provider);
```

then angular will look for `'MickeyMouseProviderProvider'`

Hope this saves you a bit of time.